# How do I convert a multiple-part VMDK disk image to qcow2?

Tags: vmware, qemu

I have a VMDK disk image that exists as multiple files:

```
2.0G guest-s001.vmdk  1.8G guest-s003.vmdk  128K guest-s005.vmdk
2.0G guest-s002.vmdk  1.7G guest-s004.vmdk  4.0K guest.vmdk
```

When running `qemu-img` to convert it to the qcow2 format, which input filename(s) should I specify? Just `guest.vmdk`, all of them, or something like `guest-*.vmdk`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the past, I've had to convert them first to raw images, concatenate them together, and then convert the resulting raw image to qcow2:

```
qemu-img convert guest-s001.vmdk guest-s0001.raw
qemu-img convert guest-s002.vmdk guest-s0002.raw
qemu-img convert guest-s003.vmdk guest-s0003.raw
qemu-img convert guest-s004.vmdk guest-s0004.raw
qemu-img convert guest-s005.vmdk guest-s0005.raw
cat guest-s0001.raw guest-s0002.raw guest-s0003.raw guest-s0004.raw guest-s0005.raw > guest.raw
qemu-img convert guest.raw guest.qcow2
```

Don't panic if more than just the last file is smaller than 2146762752 bytes. Some VMware products create vmdk spans with different sizes. The size should match 512 times the number of sectors listed in the extent description in the main vmdk file (readable with any text editor or "cat").

It may be possible to do this all at once too, but I haven't tried this:

```
qemu-img convert guest-s001.vmdk guest-s002.vmdk guest-s003.vmdk guest-s004.vmdk guest-s005.vmdk guest.qcow2
```

Or, if they're not actually contiguous disk images, then I'm not sure what to suggest. :)

Good luck!

---

A quick terminal script to convert all of the images at once would be:

```
for i in *.vmdk; do qemu-img convert -f vmdk $i -O raw $i.raw; done
cat *.raw > tmpImage.raw
qemu-img convert tmpImage.raw finalImage.qcow2
rm *.raw
```

Comment: qemu-img convert guest-s001.vmdk guest-s002.vmdk guest-s003.vmdk guest-s004.vmdk guest-s005.vmdk guest.qcow2


this method is possible, quick, comfortable !!!!
Thank you :)

Comment: Love it.  consider prepending "IFS=\n ;" to your for loop just in case the vmdk files have spaces in the names. 
`IFS=\n ; for i in *.vmdk; do qemu-img 
convert -f vmdk $i -O raw $i.raw; done
&&
cat *.raw > tmpImage.raw
&&
qemu-img convert tmpImage.raw finalImage.qcow2
&&
rm *.raw`

Comment: Plain `qemu-img convert guest.vmdk` works, no need to convert/concatenate the individual files. Check the answer below

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the qemu-img command has been enhanced now. I just converted a bunch of VMware multi-part images to qcow2 with the command:

```
$ qemu-img convert <base of the image without the S0001,2etc>.vmdk new-image.qcow2
```

Comment: This oddly produced a "raw" image. For a qcow2 one, I had to write `qemu-img convert -O qcow2 …`

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers actually worked as of QEMU 7.1.0.  It became as trivial as working on the single small .vmdk file that references the other larger vmdk image files.  Supposing you have the following collections of files:

```
'your-vm-s001.vmdk'        
'your-vm-s002.vmdk'
'your-vm-s003.vmdk'
[...]
'your-vm-s011.vmdk'
'your-vm-s012.vmdk'
'your-vm.vmdk'
```

Then you should simply invoke `qemu-img` like:

```
qemu-img convert -fvmdk -Oqcow2 your-vm.vmdk your-vm.qcow2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying this to convert to raw:

```
find . -type f -iname <guest-name>\*-f0\*vmdk -exec qemu-img convert {} {}.raw \;
```

Then to catenate:

```
cat <guest-name>*-f0[0-1][1-9]*raw >> <guest-name>.raw
```

Then to convert:

```
qemu-img convert <guest-name>.raw -O qcow2 <guest-name>.qcow2
```

Answer (score 1):

I could have used `parallel` to do this but here is one that will do the directory:

```
ls *s0??.vdmk | xargs -n 2 -I % qemu-img convert % %.img
```

And then:

```
cat *.img >> imagename.raw
```

The `ls` part before the pipe will print all vdmk that have at the end an `s0` and two wildcards the `xargs` command allows it to substitute `%` twice as a variable to the end of the `qemu-img` command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do it in one line, making use of [arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays):

```
files=(*s0??.vmdk); qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O qcow2 ${files[@]} ${files%-s001.vmdk}.qcow2;
```

Comment: Nice idea, though it'd be best to quote the expansion of the array in case the input file names have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use wildcard in the name of images:

```
qemu-img convert my-multipart-image*.vmdk my-image.qcow2
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above examples did the job for me and neither did other solutions I found on the web so here you go with an updated version that works.

Filenames: **Windows.10-s00{1,16}.vmdk** is stored in the vmware path but also notice the single .vmdk file that is: ~4.0kb in your folder: This is how it looks for my setup: **Windows.10.vmdk** choose this minimal file as 'target' and then qemu-img will do the job fo us:

```
 4.0G       Windows.10-s001.vmdk
 4.0G       Windows.10-s002.vmdk
 4.0G       Windows.10-s003.vmdk
 4.0G       Windows.10-s004.vmdk
 4.0G       Windows.10-s005.vmdk
 4.0G       Windows.10-s006.vmdk
 4.0G       Windows.10-s007.vmdk
 3.8G       Windows.10-s008.vmdk
 12K        Windows.10-s009.vmdk
 12K        Windows.10-s010.vmdk
 12K        Windows.10-s011.vmdk
 12K        Windows.10-s012.vmdk
 12K        Windows.10-s013.vmdk
 12K        Windows.10-s014.vmdk
 12K        Windows.10-s015.vmdk
 144K       Windows.10-s016.vmdk
 4.0K       Windows.10.vmdk
```

- Convert vmdk > qcow2 with below command:

  ```
  qemu-img convert Windows.10.vmdk Windows.10.qcow
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I just resurrected a 10 year old offline root certificate authority that had run on VmWare Workstation and so have had opportunity to verify @Stuart's answer as correct as of QEMU version 6.2.0 (probably earlier).  `qemu-img convert` will indeed recombine all the files into a single .qcow2 file.  But ...

It is critical that you identify and use the "top" file in the backing chain as the source file in `qemu-img convert` - you cannot reliably identify the top file by VmWare's naming conventions - they vary apparently.

Use `qemu-img info --backing-chain` to reveal the "top" file.

Here is a script to list the backing chains for all your .vmdk files:

```
for i in `ls *.vmdk`
do 
echo $i
qemu-img info --backing-chain $i|grep "backing file:"
done
```

The file that has ALL the other .vmdk files in the backing chain is the one you want to submit to `qemu-img convert` as the top file.  It will then take care of combining them all into the output file.  Syntax:

```
qemu-img convert -p[c] [-f vmdk] -O qcow2 \
[-o nocow=on] <top_file>.vmdk output.qcow2
```

optional arguments:

**-c** Compresses the output file.  Slower but produces a smaller file.  Desirable if the output will be copied elsewhere.

**-f vmdk** Specifies the type of input file but if you were successful at listing the backing chain, qemu-img is certain to figure this out on it's own.

**-o nocow=on** Turns off Copy on Write for the file.  This is desirable for performance reasons if the target file system is already COW (like btrfs).