# How do I convert one monolithic vmdk to split vmdk(s) using qemu-img

Tags: vmware, qemu, vmdk

I am running VMware Player 15.5.1 on Windows 10 x64 with QEMU for Windows 20200201.

TL;DR: How do I convert a monolithic vmdk (3.7GB) to split vmdk(s) (2GB each) via `qemu-img`?

I downloaded a demo vmdk and hoping to test it out, I loaded it into a VM and pressed play. However, since my drive "can't support" monolithic vmdk files over 2GB, it wouldn't start up. Looking on the VMware site, I found instructions on how to so, however it only supported VMware Workstation. Given that I have QEMU (I don't use it often), I figured that I could use `qemu-img` to convert it to an acceptable format. I found [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4398/how-do-i-convert-a-multiple-part-vmdk-disk-image-to-qcow2) on askubuntu that combines a split vmdk into a monolithic vmdk, however it seems unlikely that it would work backwards. Is it possible to split the vmdk up using `qemu-img`?

Link to VMDK: https://download.automotivelinux.org/AGL/release/icefish/9.0.1/qemux86-64/deploy/images/qemux86-64/agl-demo-platform-crosssdk-qemux86-64.wic.vmdk

Comment: Which version of Linux and which release number is in use? Different releases have different tools. Please click [edit] and add that to your question; please do not use Add Comment as that's our one-way channel to you.

Comment: can  you share the link of the demo vmdk ?

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox  with the tool VBoxManage can convert image between format

So in your case :

```
VBoxManage clonemedium agl-demo-platform-crosssdk-qemux86-64.wic.vmdk  new-agl-demo-platform-crosssdk-qemux86-64.wic.vmdk  --format VMDK --variant Split2G

em444-mbp:tmp em444$ ls -la
total 15128328
-rw-r--r--   1 em444  wheel  3861708800 May 18 15:40 agl-demo-platform-crosssdk-qemux86-64.wic.vmdk
-rw-------   1 em444  wheel  2084241408 May 18 15:46 new-agl-demo-platform-crosssdk-qemux86-64.wic-s001.vmdk
-rw-------   1 em444  wheel  1776812032 May 18 15:46 new-agl-demo-platform-crosssdk-qemux86-64.wic-s002.vmdk
-rw-------   1 em444  wheel      393216 May 18 15:46 new-agl-demo-platform-crosssdk-qemux86-64.wic-s003.vmdk
-rw-------   1 em444  wheel      458752 May 18 15:46 new-agl-demo-platform-crosssdk-qemux86-64.wic-s004.vmdk
-rw-------   1 em444  wheel         835 May 18 15:46 new-agl-demo-platform-crosssdk-qemux86-64.wic.vmdk
```

The only drawback is that the disk will be register in the virtualbox registry .

If you want do repeat again the operation you need before to run

```
VBoxManage closemedium /private/tmp/tmp/new-agl-demo-platform-crosssdk-qemux86-64.wic.vmdk
```